# Does foreach copy each element if it is an array of structs?

Tags: c#, .net

I have an array of structs. Does `foreach` operator make a copy of each element when iterating thru an array? As far as I understand `foreach` is just syntactic sugar under the hood converted to `for`. So it appears the answer is no but I'd love to have some confirmation.

PS: it appears someone should have already asked that but I can't easily find anything. So please vote as a dup with provided reference.

Comment: Are you wanting to know if foreach makes a copy to the reference variable?  Example: foreach(IPAddress ips in IPList)  Reference variable here being ips.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, copies of the value type instances will be made.  When iterating over an array, `foreach` will indeed use array accesses instead of using an enumerator, but the value in each array slot is still copied.

This code:

```
struct AStruct
{
    public string a;
    public int b;

    static void Main()
    {
        var structs = new AStruct[10];

        foreach (var x in structs) {
            Console.WriteLine(x);
        }
    }
}
```

Generates the following IL for the `Main()` method:

```
.method private static hidebysig
       default void Main ()  cil managed
{
    .entrypoint
    .maxstack 4
    .locals init (
            valuetype AStruct[]     V_0,
            valuetype AStruct[]     V_1,
            int32   V_2,
            valuetype AStruct       V_3)
    IL_0000:  ldc.i4.s 0x0a
    IL_0002:  newarr AStruct
    IL_0007:  stloc.0
    IL_0008:  ldloc.0
    IL_0009:  stloc.1
    IL_000a:  ldc.i4.0
    IL_000b:  stloc.2
    IL_000c:  br IL_002d

    IL_0011:  ldloc.1
    IL_0012:  ldloc.2
    IL_0013:  ldelema AStruct
    IL_0018:  ldobj AStruct
    IL_001d:  stloc.3
    IL_001e:  ldloc.3
    IL_001f:  box AStruct
    IL_0024:  call void class [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(object)
    IL_0029:  ldloc.2
    IL_002a:  ldc.i4.1
    IL_002b:  add
    IL_002c:  stloc.2
    IL_002d:  ldloc.2
    IL_002e:  ldloc.1
    IL_002f:  ldlen
    IL_0030:  conv.i4
    IL_0031:  blt IL_0011

    IL_0036:  ret
} // end of method AStruct::Main
```

Note the instructions IL_0013 through IL_001d.  The entire value at each array slot is pushed onto the stack and stored in the local V_3 (the `x` iteration variable).

Comment: So in other words, whichever I use, it doesn't matter. Thanks! Now when I think about after reading what problems people have using structs and `foreach` I think I understand why. Structs are value types. In degenerate case, say, of using `int` there is hardly a way not to copy its value to the stack. Thus the struct is also copied. Thanks again though - it's undeniably the fullest answer.

Comment: Not necessarily.  If you use a `for` loop and access the array by index, you will not necessarily create copies. In that case the `ldelema` instruction will be used, but `ldobj` (the part that copies the value onto the stack) may not, depending on what you are doing with the instance.

Comment: @Schultz9999 It uses direct array access to copy each value in the array into the iteration variable `x`.  I mean this as opposed to using an enumerator object and `IEnumerator.Current` to access the value. In *both* cases, the value will be copied. (But the value to be copied will be obtained with fewer levels of indirection.)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23001/discussion-between-cdhowie-and-schultz9999)